# django signals - getting it right

Tags: python, django, django-signals

This is the first time I've used signals, and I'm utilising them as a learning curve, but I wish to make sure that I'm getting things right.

I'm utilising the post_save signal for a model (for all intents and purposes lets call it `ModelA`) which upon being saved I wish it to send a signal to send the data to my api app.

**signals.py**

```
def apiCall_Update(sender, **kwargs):
    ...

post_save.connect(apiCall_Update, sender=ModelA, dispatch_uid='Update')
```

I'm using an UpdateView to update the model in this instance

```
class UpdateModelA(UpdateView):
    model = ModelA
    slug_field = 'name'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'name'
    template_name_suffix = "_update_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('modela_manager')
```

`ModelA` updates perfectly fine when this view is run, however I'm not getting the post_save signal being triggered.  I could be clutching at thin air here and be doing the completely wrong thing.  I have tried various resources including the docs and other stacks to see if I can debug this myself, but I'm doing everything I have been reading and I am none-the-wiser as to the correct method of doing this.

Comment: Could you talk about some debugging attempts?  Have you verified that `apiCall_Update` doesn't get run?  If so, how?

Comment: My main problem, is that I'm not 100% on how to debug this kind of thing, if you could provide some guidance I would happily attempt debugging it further.  I mentioned that I have read other resources to see if I can debug it, but yet to find anything sufficient to guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems that it was purely down to the signals not being loaded.

I achieved the result I was after, by importing the signals into the models.py that they were related to.

```
from myapp import signals
```

This applies when the signals are in their own file (I wrote them into a signals.py in the apps folder)